# How to test asp.net controller to upload multiple files in postman

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, postman

Using postman, I upload multiple files to my controller api using below code

```
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage UploadFile()
    {
        foreach (string file in Request.Files)
        {
            var FileDataContent = Request.Files[file];
            if (FileDataContent != null && FileDataContent.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                // take the input stream, and save it to a temp folder using the original file.part name posted
                var stream = FileDataContent.InputStream;
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileDataContent.FileName);
                var UploadPath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads");
                Directory.CreateDirectory(UploadPath);
                string path = Path.Combine(UploadPath, fileName);
                try
                {
                    if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
                        System.IO.File.Delete(path);
                    using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(path))
                    {
                        stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
                    }
                    // Once the file part is saved, see if we have enough to merge it
                    Shared.Utils UT = new Shared.Utils();
                    UT.MergeFile(path);
                }
                catch (IOException ex)
                {
                    // handle
                    Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
        HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage()
        {
            StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK,
            Content = new StringContent("File uploaded.")
        };

        return result;
```

And in postman

[image]

However, when I breakpoint at start of the api, the Request.Files is empty, that is why I return don't go inside the foreach loop and exit the api immediately with success.

Why is my Request.Files empty when I send in Postman? How do I test this multiple file upload in postman?

I tried to edit what I send to postman by making the files on the body an array, but still I can't send the file to be debugged in my api

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working fine no need to use **[]** with the key just add multiple fields with the same key and postman will converts them to array.
[image]

[image]